# Websphere jmx query to get security domain

Tags: websphere, jmx, jmx-ws

I am using Websphere Applicaiton Server 8.5 and using JMX code in my client to get values from Websphere such as: cells, nodes and datasources using query strings like: *_Websphere_Config_Data_Display_Name, WebSphere:type=DataSource,name=* respectively. But I am not able to figure out what query string to use in the JMX call to get all security domains in my Websphere application server. I can achieve this using jython: AdminTask.listSecurityDomains('-listDescription true')

and using jacl:

$AdminTask listSecurityDomains.

But I want to do this using a JMX call due to performance reasons: to create a script(jacl or python) and then to run it by exec() of wsadmin to fetch my domains would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

you could try with Java program that uses Python Interpreter.

please check this 
http://blog.smartbear.com/programming/embedding-jython-in-java-applications/